# Expresso Store modifier select in checkout

Tags: expresso-store, checkout, modifiers, product

I would like to add the option the change the product modifiers from inside the checkout. I've done some tried some things already but don't seem to be able to manage this. At the moment I'm using an embed function to display the modifiers select per product in my checkout which is working. Though the update seems to ignore this select.

My current code is like this:

```
{exp:store:checkout form_class="form-horizontal" return="{segment_1}/order_ok/ORDER_HASH/"}
   {items}
     {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}" site="sales"  status="not closed"}
       <tr>
         <td>{title}</td>
         <td>
           {modifiers}
             {embed="us/_product-modifiers" entry_id="{entry_id}" key="{key}" option_id="{option_id}" modifier_id="{modifier_input_name}"}
           {/modifiers}
         </td>
         <td>
            <div class="input-group">
               <input type="text" name="items[{key}][item_qty]" value="{item_qty}" class="form-control qty" placeholder="1">
            </div>
       </tr>
     {/exp:channel:entries}
   {/items}
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

The embed I'm using:

```
{exp:store:product entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" disable_form="yes" disable_javascript="yes"}

  {modifiers}
    {if modifier_type == 'var' OR modifier_type == 'var_single_sku'}
        <select name="items[{embed:key}][{embed:modifier_id}]">
            {modifier_options}
                <option value="{option_id}" {if "{embed:option_id}" == "{option_id}"}selected="selected"{/if}>
                    {option_name}
                </option>
            {/modifier_options}
        </select>
    {/if}
  {/modifiers}

{/exp:store:product}
```

I'm not entirely sure if it's even possible without modifying the store code itself as there isn't really anything about it in the documentation from what I can see. Has someone encountered the same problem already or might know a solution to this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store module: How to update product modifier from the cart page?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/store-module-how-to-update-product-modifier-from-the-cart-page)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the marked duplicate above no longer works as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer you need is in one of the 2 answers given here mate : [Store module: How to update product modifier from the cart page?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/store-module-how-to-update-product-modifier-from-the-cart-page)

Comment: Yeah that's indeed what I'm looking for, though this topic doesn't seem to be working anymore. It looks as if the update function has changed since then.

Comment: Ahh, bummer. Ok well we'll need to work through their input... give me a chance to have a look (also one of the repeat offenders here that support Expresso might chirp in too!

Comment: There are probably a few reasons why the solution above would not work the `store_cart_update_start` was an extension hook in Store v1 not Store v2. It requires that you create an extension so it is not just add some template code and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian mentioned in the previously mentioned link this is not a normal behavior for Store as it see items with different modifiers/skus as separate line items in the cart.

> The underlying issue you are running into here is that Store treats
>   any products with different modifiers as separate line items in your
>   cart (for example if you add a Red Shirt and Blue Shirt to your cart,
>   it would not make sense to merge them into a single line item on the
>   invoice). That is why when you try to update the "modifier", it adds a
>   new line item to the cart.

So in Store v2 you are still really faced with the same two options:

1.)

> Write an extension with a custom form action URL, which edits the cart
>   directly in the database (this is easier than it sounds, you can use
>   our cart library to recalculate everything once you change the
>   modifiers)

This is what Brian did when he tapped into the `store_cart_update_start` hook in Store v1. You could create the same functionality in Store v2 by using one of the [order_update hooks](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html#order_update_hooks)

OR

2.)

> Remove the existing product and add a new product. This would require
>   some javascript to make two sequential form submissions seem like a
>   single step to the customer, because the checkout form and product
>   form have different action URLs.

If you are not comfortable with php this would be your best best, you could open a modal that allows the customer to add a new product to the cart with the correct modifiers and then deletes the product with the different modifiers from the cart.